# Java regex: Match URLs with spaces and brackets

Tags: java, regex, url

With Java Regex, I am not able to match URL's which have spaces, ( and ) brackets, below is a code example, can you please help. Only last URL's `E.jpeg` works.

**Code**:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String content = "Lorem ipsum https://example.com/A B 123 4.pdf   https://example.com/(C.jpeg   https://example.com/D).jpeg   https://example.com/E.jpeg";
    extractUrls(content);
}

public static void extractUrls(String text) {
    Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("(https?)://[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-zA-Z0-9+&@#/%=~_|]", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pat.matcher(text);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    }
}
```

**Output**:

```
https://example.com/A
https://example.com/
https://example.com/D
https://example.com/E.jpeg
```

**Expected output:**

```
https://example.com/A B 123 4.pdf
https://example.com/(C.jpeg
https://example.com/D).jpeg
https://example.com/E.jpeg
```

Comment: Try using a non greedy quantifier `http.*?\.(?:pdf|jpe?g)` https://regex101.com/r/bNiUcY/1 Or use the character class to make the `.` more specific.

Comment: I thought URLs used "+" instead of spaces

Comment: Hello "The fourth bird":: 
For text: https://example.com/(C.docx  -> 
I used: https.*?\\.(?:jpg|jpeg|png|pdf|doc|docx)  -> 
But it drops 'x' from 'docx' and shows as --> 
https://example.com/(C.doc

Comment: Use `docx|doc` instead

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this code:

```
import java.lang.Math; 
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String content = "Lorem ipsum https://example.com/A B 123 4.pdf   https://example.com/(C.jpeg   https://example.com/D).jpeg   https://example.com/E.jpeg";
        extractUrls(content);
    }

    public static void extractUrls(String text) {
        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("(https?)://(([\\S]+)(\\s)?)*", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
        Matcher matcher = pat.matcher(text);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println(matcher.group());
        }
    }
}
```

**The output:**

```
https://example.com/A B 123 4.pdf 
https://example.com/(C.jpeg 
https://example.com/D).jpeg 
https://example.com/E.jpeg
```

**Explaining:**

I assume the file name does not have two consecutive blank spaces, as shown in the examples.

The `(https?)://` identifies the substrings `http://` or `https://`.

We have two groups on this piece: `(([\\S]+)(\\s)?`. It identifies 1 or more characters (other than white space) followed by only 1 or 0 blank characters.

With the character `*` this process can be repeated several times.

Therefore our expression understands that if there are 2 or more blank spaces, it is the separation between two filenames.

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Answer from "The fourth bird" user solved this problem, regex should be:

```
http.*?\.(?:pdf|jpe?g)
```